# The CPU idle is set to 99 while using vmstat, what does this mean?

Tags: performance, vmstat

I am confused with the CPU idle time is set to 99. Does this mean the CPU is idle not doing anything for 99% of the time?

```
#vmstate
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu------
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  0   2336  18512 263972 1048992   0    0    1     47   0    0  0  0  99  0  0
```

Answer (score 4):

Please note, that on most unix systems first line of vmstat output is average since last reboot. Next lines are current statistics.

99% CPU Idle means that your server is not really heavy loaded. Which is good. Nothing to worry about :)

Answer (score 3):

Idle time means your CPU is doing nothing. Your system is not performing any work, so your CPU is spending time idling.